# Error Call to a member function roles() on null (View: C:

Tags: laravel

I am currently experinecing this error now, which was not happening before, I have been trying to troubleshoot but not getting it right.
Below is the error line code.

```
                     Actions</th>

                                </tr>

                            </thead>

                            <tbody>

                                @php

                                    $count = 1;

                                @endphp

                                @foreach ($accounts as $account)

                                    <tr role="row" class="odd">

                                        <td class="sorting_1">{{ $count++ }}</td>

                                        <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($account->created_at)) 
                         }}</td>

                                        <td><label data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ $account- 
               >status == 'completed' ? 'Confirmed on ' . date('F d, Y', strtotime($account- 
               >confirmed_at)) : 'pending confirmation' }}" style="border: none; background:

                                        @role('admin')

                                            <td><a href="{{ route('staff.edit', $account- 
              >createdBy) }}" target="_blank">{{ $account->createdBy->name }}</a></td>

                                            <td>
```

//error is pointing to  <a href="@if ($account->user->roles()- >first()->name == 'agent')

```
                   {{ route('agents.edit', $account->user) }} 
              @else {{ route('staff.edit', $account->user) }}

                     @endif" target="_blank">{{ $account->user- >name }}</a>

                                            </td>

                                        @endrole

                                        <td>{{ $account->rsa_pin }}</td>

                                        <td>{{ $account->ref_no }}</td>

                                        <td>{{ $account->name }}</td>

                                        <td>{{ $account->phone }}</td>

                                        <td>{{ $account->employer }}</td>

                                        <td>

                                            @role('agent')

                                                <a href="mailto:{{$account->createdBy- 
                 >email}}?subject=RSA Agent Query&cc=tfweb@trustfundpensions.com">

                                                    <button class="btn btn-outline- 
                 primary">Send Mail</button>

                                                </a>

                                            @endrole
```

I have tried all I could but no solution.
Kindly help me out

Comment: `$account->user->roles()->first()->name`; if any of those `->` calls return `null`, that code will break. In your case `$account->user` is `null`, and `null->roles()` doesn't work. You need to add some code to handle that, like `if ($account->user) { // Do something with $account->user->roles()->first() }`

Answer (score 0):

```
($account->user->roles()- >first()->name == 'agent')
```

The error means that $account has no user which means it's null and you are trying to grab roles() of the null which throws error.

In this case you do some checks if $account has user.
Some fast example:

```
$account->user ? $account->user->roles()- >first()->name == 'agent' : // your else logic
```